# How to reduce higher values to 1s and sort the ones from right to left

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to make a python program that quickly reduces a number greater than 1 in an array/list and places it in an empty spot before it. Say we have:

```
li = [4,1,0,0,0,1,3,0]
```

we'd get:

```
rtr = [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
```

Note how the 4 turns into a 1 because it's already to the left and then the 3 gets divided into 2 positions before the 1 that has already been taken. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: If 3 turns into 2 1's to the left of its existing position, why are there four 1's where there used to be `1,3`? Shouldn't the result be `[1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]` (based on your text description)?

Comment: The 3 means that 3 ones are stored there, that need to be divided towards the left, and because there is already a 1 in that position before it, there are 4 ones in total in that position

Comment: Then why doesn't the 4 turn into four 1's by this same logic?

Comment: Because that 4 is already at the most left position, that's the twist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate the list from end to start and keep track of the sum you collect from the values. When you have a non zero sum, take 1 from it to populate the result list, and otherwise put a 0 in the result list.

Here is how that could work:

```
def spread(lst):
    carry = 0
    res = []
    for i in reversed(lst):
        carry += i
        res.append(int(carry > 0))
        if carry:
            carry -= 1 
    return list(reversed(res))

lst = [4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0]
print(spread(lst))  # [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy

```
def fun(l):
  s = np.array(l[::-1])    
  for i in range(len(s)):
      if s[i] != 1 and s[i] != 0:
        x = s[i+1:]
        x[(x == 0).nonzero()[0][:s[i]-1]] = 1
        s[i] = 1
  return s[::-1].tolist()

print (fun([4,1,0,0,0,1,3,0]))
print (fun([0, 10]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1]
```

Comment: @superbrain thanks for pointing it out. Updated the answer to a better and faster version